# Is it posible to embed SSRS rdl reports in Visual Studio 2003 (.NET 1.1)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reporting-services

I just want to know if such thing is possible. I do not need to know whether I can migrate to a newer version of .NET, etc. This specific version of the technology I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed SSRS reports in a visual studio project, you need to have a ReportViewer and it requires .NET 2.0

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3db9b70-1dc0-480a-951c-3c488760b65f/report-viewer-control-for-visual-studio-2003?forum=vsreportcontrols